# JGit scalability limitation

Tags: java, git, github, jgit

I am using JGit for my project where i have to maintain the files uploaded by the users.
If the file already existing then it would create a new version of the same and associate the customer with his commited/uploaded set of files.

It works file locally i.e each file one uploads , commit it to repository i.e. on server machine and adds the same recored in the DB , to associate the customer and its respective file versioning lists i.e. commitIds.

But after few iterations of upload files (each upload may consists around 200 files) , JGit able to commit the files and generate the commitIds properly but not able to retreive the content of the files when showing the user back his commmitted files.

Unfortunately log does not show any errors while retreiving the files.

Hence i am lost ....and struggling to understand stand what is wrong here.

My questions are:

1. Does the JGIT have enough scalability ? i.e. fetch time would be fast enough as it grows?
2. what to do if i retrieve the files properly.

Below is the piece of code which i am using

```
FileUtils.copyFile(aFile,destFile);
AddCommand add = git.add();
add.addFilepattern(".").call();
CommitCommand commit = git.commit();
commit.setAuthor(user.getFirstName(), user.getUserId());
commit.setMessage("comments" ).call();
ObjectId lastCommitId = git.getRepository().resolve(org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Constants.HEAD);
```

Above destFile is GIT repository and aFile is the file name

Using the lastCommitId i am trying to retrive the content of the file but me getting the:

```
MissingObjectException: Missing unknown 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Code used to retreive the file is:

```
ObjectId lastCommitId = repo.resolve(lastCommitId);

RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repo);
treeWalk.addTree(tree);
treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create("actial_File_Name"));  //this is actual file name i used

boolean next = treeWalk.next();
if (next) 
{
    ObjectId objectId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
    log.logError(" objectId :" + objectId );
    try{
        ObjectLoader loader = repo.open(objectId);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetFile); ///targetFile is the actual file name i wanted to retreive the content i.e orginal name
        loader.copyTo(out);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'missing unknown 0000' seems to suggest that one of your references is missing, and the null is being returned for the objectId. You should check to see if the `objectId.equals(ObjectId.zeroId())` when you do the lookup.

You might also want to check to see if the repository needs garbage collection (either with JGit or a standalone Git client) - by default JGit doesn't do automatic garbage collection.

Note also that a commit doesn't get inserted into the database until you call the `call()` method and you get a commit back again. Maybe that's why you can't find it in your code?

Comment: Thank you AlBlue , but why first of all me getting zeroId when there is an object with that commitId exists in the repository ? How to avoid getting "MissingObjectException: Missing unknown 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ?

Comment: In your code, are you attempting to get the commit in the same process as generating it?

I note that you don't appear to be doing a `call()` which actually persists it to the database. So any attempt to open that commit will generate a missing object exception because a commit's id is `0000...` before it is committed with `call()`.